# Why i am not able to pass optional value ( ? ) for getting image url?

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa-touch

```
self.imgView .sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: dictData["image"] as? String))
```

Hello I am using swift and I want to get image URL from dictData but when I Write this line

`dictData["image"] as? String`

it's giving error like this `Value of optional type 'String?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?` and when I click on the error its improve my line of code by this

`dictData["image"] as! String`

Why this happened? I want to know the  reason behind that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means `dictData["image"] as? String` is an optional. And `NSURL(string)` takes a non optional parameter. In order to do so you have to unwrap the optional. `dictData["image"] as! String` is force unwrapping which means, if `dictData["image"]` is `nil` or if it fails to cast to String your app will crash. I encourage you to use the following code

```
if let image = dictData["image"] as? String {
        self.imgView .sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: image))
} else {
        print("failed to cast to String")
}
```

Comment: Great Explanation @LIH. Thanks:)

Comment: @IOSDev, If this worked, consider marking as the answer

Comment: @LIH Thanks its Works .

Answer (score 2):

First, your dictData which is a Dictionary should be initialize as

`var dictData: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>`

or You can use the new `[KeyType: ValueType]` annotation instead of `Dictionary<KeyType, ValueType>`.

```
if let url = dictData["image"] as? String {
    // no error
}
```

Comment: @Khusboo Motwani  Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

`NSURL` initialiser accepts only non-optional value. When you do the casting `dictData["image"] as? String` it may fail and return `nil`.

What you have to do is to make sure you initialise url only when you have an object in place:

```
if let url = dictData["image"] as? String {
    self.imgView.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: url))
}
```